# How to merge two tables from two different work sheets into one final table with different columns?

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to coding (a newbie).

At work place, I have following to do:

A) I have Table A
B) I have Table B
C) I need output Table C (how do I get it?)

I am describing in details here:

Input Tables A and B:

[image]

Output Table C:

[image]

I have to get Output table C for many many files and thus will be very difficult to match up Order and Order-1 in the Tables using copy and past option in excel.

Thanks a ton for looking into this.

Apologies if the question is not clear.

Please let me know if you need any further information regarding this.

Comment: Why is there **mysql** tag on the question?

Comment: Apologies...I do not know much about coding and I chose the three options suggested. Apologies again.

Comment: Have you tried anything to achieve this?

Comment: Yes looking at MYSQL first..

Answer (score 1):

You can try taking a `UNION` of the two tables:

```
SELECT Time, Type, User,    '', Order-1, Urea
FROM TableA
UNION ALL
SELECT Time,   '', User, Order, Order-1, Urea
FROM TableB
ORDER BY Time
```

If you're not really using MySQL, then you should not have tagged your question as such, which generated an answer like this one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Even though the data is Excel not MySQL, I think this answer is still very useful, OP might try connect to Excel using ADO and use this query to generate a Recordset and use `Range.CopyFromRecordset`.

Comment: @Rahul007 If you're going to do this from Excel/VBA, then get ready for some ugly column manipulations.  You'll have to do the same thing my query does, except through code (VBA), or by hand Excel.  Once the target has the right column structure, you can just dump both sets of data and then sort.

Comment: Thanks A.S.H and Tim....I will look what ADO is....Tim has given great suggestion....just that I need to see how to do it (will see how to install SQL and connect it with excel).

Comment: One more followup question: Say I need to order by another column...say "Order-1" first followed by time...so the final code will be...Order by Order-1 (followed by) Order by Time....is that the right way?

Comment: Use `ORDER BY Order-1, time` ... separate the terms by comma, with the first sort coming first, the last sort coming last.

Comment: Tim, Thanks again! I have installed SQL server, added Table A and Table B as separate csv files to MYSQL Workbench...now trying to figure out how to link the two tables (which I have added to MYSQL Workbench) to your code to merge tables....after that I will be exporting data back to excel.

Comment: 'Mission Accomplished!' Thanks to ALL....No words to thank you all :) :) :)

Answer (score 1):

this is Vba of SQL.  practice sub myQuery.

```
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim strSQL As String

Sub myQuery()

Set Ws = Sheets("C")

    strSQL = "SELECT Time, Type, User, '' as [Order], [Order-1], Urea"
    strSQL = strSQL & " FROM [A$] where not isnull(Time) "
    strSQL = strSQL & " Union All  "
    strSQL = strSQL & "SELECT Time, '', User, [Order], [Order-1], Urea "
    strSQL = strSQL & "FROM [B$] where not isnull(time) "
    strSQL = strSQL & "ORDER BY Time "

    DoSQL

End Sub
Sub DoSQL()

    Dim Rs As Object
    Dim strConn As String
    Dim i As Integer

    strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
            "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"


    Set Rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Rs.Open strSQL, strConn

    If Not Rs.EOF Then
         With Ws
            .Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Clear
            For i = 0 To Rs.Fields.Count - 1
               .Cells(1, i + 1).Value = Rs.Fields(i).Name
            Next
            .Range("a" & 2).CopyFromRecordset Rs
            .Columns(1).NumberFormatLocal = "[$-409]mm/dd/yy h:mm AM/PM;@"
        End With
    End If
    Rs.Close
    Set Rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: A,B,C  is sheet name.

Comment: Thanks a ton Dy. Lee!