# Getting errors while trying to open a Excel file with ADO

Tags: excel, connection-string, ado, vba

I'm trying to get some values from an Excel file (.xls) using ADO with SQL queries. However I'm getting error while trying to open the connection. This is what I have currently:

```
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

strFile = IIf(strPath <> "", strPath, Range("G13").Value)
If strFile = "" Then Exit Sub

strCon = "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strFile & ";'Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1';"

strCon2 = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFile & ";'Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES';"

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

cn.Open strCon2
```

I have tested using both my connection strings (strCon, strCon2) with no success. I either get an error with no text only an "x" symbol. Or a `"System Error &H80004005 (-2147467259)"`

### Edit:

Changed it so I open recordset instead, however it still gives me the same error.

```
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

strFile = IIf(strPath <> "", strPath, Range("G13").Value)
If strFile = "" Then Exit Sub

strCon = "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" & _
          strFile & "';'Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1';"

strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=" & strFile & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

'cn.Open strCon

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet11$C5]"

rs.Open strSQL, strConn

Debug.Print rs.GetString
```

Comment: Yes the value is referenced correctly. strFile is always correct and it's at cn.Open the error occurs

Comment: refer to This  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44747265/how-to-merge-two-tables-from-two-different-work-sheets-into-one-final-table-with/44747932?noredirect=1#comment76477371_44747932) . you missed sql and rs.open not cn.open.

Comment: @Dy.Lee see my edit, error still occurs

Comment: Can you submit the strPath and  Range("G13").Value?

Comment: strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet11$C5]"
seems to be strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet11$]"

Comment: `C:\Users\gbox\Test - Excel\source.XLS` is the path. And how can the SQL string not be "$C5"?

Comment: strFile = IIf(strPath <> "", strPath, Range("G13").Value)
occured error.  It seems to be like this  strpath~~>  "C:\Users\gbox\Test\sourc.xls"   or  range("g3") ~~>  c:Excel\source.xls"   there needs  entire path and filename.

Comment: SQL string not be "$C5: it is not data , only one cell.

Comment: @Dy.Lee isn't a cell data? How do you select data from one cell then?

Comment: do you want get one data?

Answer (score 1):

It's too late to answer this question, but for future readers.

I had a similar problem. 
I tried to connect Excel with MySQL database, but when the recordset open, it cracks and shows me the &H80004005 error.

Finally, the problem was my office is 32 bits but my ODBC was 64 bits and this did not like it.

I changed the ODBC connection to 32 bits and the VBA function worked.