# System Error when Opening ADODB Recordset

Tags: sql, oledb, adodb, recordset

I have made a macro that does the following:

- Identifies SQL code written in Excel (Using named ranges)
- Creates/saves a text file containing the SQL query
- Runs the SQL query via an ADODB connection to SQL Server Management Studio 18
- Returns the resulting recordset back into Excel (I have the 32-bit version)

I have tested the code for many queries, and it worked as expected. However, with one query, I receive "System Error & H80004005 (-2147467259)" when I attempt to open the recordset (The line "rs.open"). The only notable qualities of this query (stored in "rs.source") are:

- The query is unusually long (Roughly 1,500 lines, whereas others were about 500)
- It produces many records (Four output tables. Two are small, two with roughly 35,000 records each)
- It accesses many data tables within SQL (9 tables)

After running a couple diagnostics, I feel pretty confident that:

**My connection string is correct**:
I have successfully used the same connection string for other SQL queries on the same server

**The SQL query is correct, and is being stored correctly**: I have manually copy, pasted and ran the text file (generated by the VBA code) in SQL Server Management Studio with success.

**The recordset's source (in VBA) is able to hold the entire query**: After assigning the recordset's source to the text file, I then wrote the recordset's source to a new text file to ensure it was storing the entire query. It was.

**It isn't the number of records or tables being produced:** I edited the query such that there is only one small recordset being produced, and I still get the same error.

I have tried to find other posts that encountered a similar error, but there didn't seem to be much out there for this issue (and the proposed solutions I found related to managing Add-ins). I will attach a snippet of the code, which errors on the line rs.Open. I'm relatively new to VBA, and extremely new to SQL (I did not write any of these SQL queries), so I apologize if I'm missing something obvious. Thank you for any guidance. [Code Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sarjl.png)

Comment: does this help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44781261/getting-errors-while-trying-to-open-a-excel-file-with-ado

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not. My ODBC driver matches my version of Excel (I have both ODBC drivers installed), and my path to the recordset source is correct. Thank you for trying to help though. Any leads are greatly appreciated